# Let $B\in M_n(\mathbb F),n\in \mathbb N.$ $M=\{x\in \mathbb F^n: xB=0\} \,\;M\leq \mathbb F^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $B\in M_n(\mathbb F),n\in \mathbb N.$
>
> $(a)$ Show that $M=\{x\in \mathbb F^n: xB=0\} \,\;M\leq \mathbb F^n$
>
> $(b)$ Find $\dim M$ with respect to the $\text{range} (B)$

My work:

By the rules of the chain matrix multiplication, $x$ has to be a one-row matrix, so of the type $1\times n.$
$$\implies xB\in M_{1 n}(\mathbb F)$$
Let $B=(b_{ij}),\;\; x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n).$
In general (bot for $B=0_n\land B\ne 0_n$
$$\implies (xB)_{1 j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i(b_{i j})=0$$
So I got:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i(b_{i j})=0$$

$M$ must contain all the linear combinations:
$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb F^n \;\forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb F$$
I stucked here.

$(b)$ $\dim M=n$ for $B=0_n$

I think $\dim M= \text{range}(B)$ because there are more ways, than the trivial one, to get a null-matrix.

Comment: Do you know about Rank–nullity theorem ?

Comment: @Mihail, no I don't. We are going to study it in a few weeks, but I wanted to solve as many tasks as possible to accumulate the material. Thank you for commenting. I will search for that in the literature.

Comment: Note also that in $(b)$ $\text{range}(B)$ is $0$ not $n$

Comment: @Mihail, thank you, yes  I see $B$ has to be fixed as the null-matrix. Is that correct?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you pick $B$ as a $0$-matrix, then $dimM=n\neq 0 = range (0)=range(B)$.

Comment: @Mihail , I understand, my mistake was then the redundant incorrect conclusion under that statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand exactly your reasoning to solve $(a)$, but I will show you how I would do it:

Clearly, the zero vector, $\textit 0$, of $F^n$ belongs to $M$, since $\textit{0}B = \textit{0}$.

Now, let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary vectors in $M$, this means $xB = \textit 0$ and $yB = \textit 0$. Also, the vector $x+y$ satisfies that

$$(x+y)B = xB + yB = \textit 0 + \textit 0 = \textit 0$$

meaning that $x+y$ is in $M$. The proof for

$$x\in M \quad \Rightarrow \quad \forall a\in F :\, ax\in M$$

is similar. Hence, $M$ is non-empty (it contains the zero vector) and its closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Therefore, $M$ is a subspace of $F^n$.

For the part $(b)$, note that $xB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$, so, $M$ is in fact the null space of $B^t$. Hence, 
$$\begin{align}
\dim(M) &= \dim( \ker(B^t))\\
&= \operatorname{nullity}(B^t).
\end{align}$$

Comment: I thought I had to prove that $x\;\&\; B$ are both zero-divisors matrices before checking  all the other conditions.